# HttpURLConnection cipher error : Could not find cipher suite

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, facebook-android-sdk

I am using android facebook sdk. Its using `httpURLConnection`. while doing
`conn.readInputStream()`. This error appeared to one of the user. It will really helpful if someone can put light on it.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find cipher suite.
at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_set_cipher_lists(Native Method)
at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.setEnabledCipherSuites(NativeCrypto.java:443)
at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:398)
at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:323)
at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.setupSecureSocket(HttpConnection.java:167)
at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:479)
at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:419)
at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl … veResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1038)
at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:523)
at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionIm … nputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:283)
at com.facebook.android.Util.openUrl(Util.java:226)
at com.facebook.android.Facebook.request(Facebook.java:538)
at com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner$2.run(AsyncFacebookRunner.java:313)
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Have you solve this? I encountered the same problem now.